# Microsoft Excel 2007 date conversion

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to convert microsoft excel date format to text format.
e.g. 01/01/2014 as First January Two thousand fourteen. 
How do I do in microsoft excel?

Comment: I've added a couple of relevant tags to attract more attention.

Answer (score 2):

I'll do the hard bit:

If your date is in cell A1 then use the formula `=TEXT(A1,"d MMMM YYYY")`. This will output `1 January 2014`. In many ways, that's the hard bit done: we've circumvented any regional date formatting and have outputted the month as a string.

The last two things are about converting the month number to "First", "Second" etc. and the year number to words. You *could* accomplish that by either lookup tables on the worksheet (cumbersome) or by using a VBA function.